# Buffer in new emacs session

Tags: session, emacs, buffer

I have a buffer in an emacs window.  And would like to display the buffer within a new emacs session using elisp code.  How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove buffer from Buffer Menu List, and all its windows in frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76933291/remove-buffer-from-buffer-menu-list-and-all-its-windows-in-frame)

Answer (score 2):

It can't be achieved. Buffers are per session; they're part of a session's state.

But any number of sessions can create their own buffers that look similar. E.g., multiple sessions can visit the same file, even at the same time. But their buffers, windows, frames, variables, etc. are separate, internal to each session.

Different sessions don't share their state. But they can visit shared external things, like files.